# Python- fillna method adding .0

Tags: python, csv, zero, fillna

I want to fill empty cells in my csv file with zeros. I found that I can do this with fillna metod. It I do this:

```
fillna(“0”)
```

This will add 0 if cell is empty but if the cell has for example 1 it is changed to 1.0 which I don’t want. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fillna("0")`, it converts the numeric values to `strings`, and that's why you see `1.0` instead of just `1`. Just fill it with `integer` instead of `strings` like that:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file.csv")

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns
convertible_cols = [col for col in float_cols if (df[col] % 1 == 0).all()]

df[convertible_cols] = df[convertible_cols].astype(int)

df.to_csv("updated_csv_file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This gives me 0.0 and not 0 and also changed the 1 to 1.0

Comment: I updated my code, I think pandas is messing arround with csv files